# Getting data from Cognito triggers

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I have an existing table of users. And I need to get data on user login. 
Is it possible to use some cognito trigger for it?

I was trying to use postAuthentication:

```
postAuthentication:
    handler: triggers.postAuthentication
    timeout: 10
    environment:
      GET_USER_LAMBDA: ${file(./env.yml):${'GET_USER_LAMBDA'}}
    events:
      - cognitoUserPool: 
          pool: ${file(./env.yml):${'POOL'}}
          trigger: PostAuthentication
          existing: true



module.exports.postAuthentication = (event, context, callback) => {
    try {
        const firstName = event.request.userAttributes['custom:firstName'];
        const lastName = event.request.userAttributes['custom:lastName'];

        lambda.invoke({
            FunctionName: GET_USER_LAMBDA,
            Payload: JSON.stringify({
                query: `${firstName}_${lastName}` 
            }, null, 2)
        })
            .promise()
            .then(data => {
                const body = JSON.parse(data['Payload']).body;

                if (body && body.Items && body.Items[0]) {
                    event.request.clientMetadata = {};
                    event.request.clientMetadata.body = JSON.stringify(body.Items[0]);

                    callback(null, event);
                } else {
                    callback(new Error(`Couldn't fetch USER`));
                }
            });

    } catch (error) {
        context.done(error);
    }
};
```

The lambda.invoke successfully returns data and there is no any errors but I can't find clientMetadata on front-end.

What trigger should I use and how to get user data?

Comment: I have the same issue, it appears you cannot return data from cognito triggers since it only returns the necessary 'event', regardless of any modified data.

Comment: `clientMetadata` is used to send data from client (e.g. in `InitiateAuth`) and is only passed to pre-auth, pre-signup and user migration triggers.